# flask load templates from an egg package

Tags: python, flask, egg, modular

I'm creating a modular flask application that loads blueprints from egg files, but those blueprints need to render templates from those packages.

This is how my project looks like:

```
some folders/
templates/ #the base folders
static/
blueprints/
  |- blueprint1.egg
  |  |- templates/ #inside the .egg
  |  |- some other folders/
  |  |- main.py
  |- blueprint2.egg
     |- templates/
     |- some other folders/
     |- main.py
my_flask_main.py
```

Now I can import and register correcly blueprints from those .egg but how can I load those templates from the .egg extracting on-the-fly them, or better read those directly from the .egg?

(Obv in dev mode when the blueprints are not packaged, it works, I need a way to load them also when the blueprints are packaged)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and testing, after some days I finally found a way to do that:

```
bp_dummy = Blueprint('dummy', __name__, template_folder='templates')

bp_dummy.jinja_loader = jinja2.ChoiceLoader([
    bp_dummy.jinja_loader,
    jinja2.PackageLoader(__name__) # in the same folder will search the 'templates' folder
])
```

First, in every blueprint instance you must define the template folder path, and override the default jinja2 template folder (by default should be a FileSystemLoader), so when the module is packaged, the default loader will fail, and the PackageLoader works.